# encountering problems when setting up venv in pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I have activated venv through cmd ,but I did not see the choice of interpreter.I expect to see the interface like this

[image]

this is my interface

[image]

What I tried is shown as above and I expect to find the same interface as the blogger on bilibili